# Loop over all observations with a unique value of a variable/column i R

Tags: r

I have dataset that looks like this:

| Chain | Product | Week | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 1 | 0 |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 2 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 51 | 10 |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 52 | 14 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 1 | 10 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 2 | 11 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 51 | 12 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 52 | 15 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 1 | 3 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 2 | 4 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 51 | 8 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 52 | 10 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 1 | 11 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 2 | 12 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 51 | 15 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 52 | 7 |

This means I have weekly observations of sales for different products and chains.
I would like to create an innovation dummy-variable which is equal to 1 when a new product is launched. This is the case for Product 1 in Chain 1 in week 51 (here, the sale goes from 0 to 10 in week 51, assuming that the sales are 0 between week 2 and 50). I then want my dummy, I, to be 1:

| Chain | Product | Week | Sales | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- | - |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 51 | 10 | 1 |
| Chain1 | Prod1 | 52 | 14 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 2 | 11 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- | - |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 51 | 12 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod1 | 52 | 15 | 0 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- | - |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 51 | 8 | 0 |
| Chain1 | Prod2 | 52 | 10 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 1 | 11 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 2 | 12 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ----- | - |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 51 | 15 | 0 |
| Chain2 | Prod2 | 52 | 7 | 0 |

I would guess I should create a loop that loops over the weekly observations of sale for each type of product in each chain and detects the when the sale starts at 0 and then changes to some value. How should this be done in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For each `Product` in each `Chain` we can find the row where first time the `Sale` value was greater than 0 and change that row value to 1. If your data is called `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Chain, Product) %>%
  mutate(I = as.integer(row_number() == match(TRUE, Sale > 0))) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I just had to add a code to ensure that 'I' will not be 1 for the first week, if the sales is greater than 0 already to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df$I <- with(df, ave(Sale > 0, Chain, Product, FUN = which.max))
```